# Какие есть инструменты, автоматически добавляющие путь к js-фалам на страницу?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Есть множество `js`-файлов. Необходимо все эти файлы подключить в `html`-файл для их загрузки. Но вручную их добавлять тяжело и могут быть еще ошибки, связанные с неверной очередностью  подключения `js`-файлов или с тем что я могу упустить некоторые файлы. И это приведет к ошибкам, в некоторых случаях очень непонятным. 
Вопрос: *есть* ли какие-нибудь инструменты, делающие данную работу автоматически, либо которые облегчают этот процесс?

**UPD1**:
Иными словами, мне надо чтобы каким-нибудь легким способом в `html`-файл добавить эти полторы сотни js-фалов. Т.е. сделать список в head файла с путями к js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="путь"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="путь"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="путь"></script>
............
```

Comment: Что-то я все-равно не понял сути, вы динамически скрипты подключаете? или хотите подключать все скрипты определенной папки? В общем - все-равно ничего не понятно

Comment: Я просто хочу добавить в html-файл, внутрь тэга <HEAD> тэги с путями к JS-файлам (<script type="text/javascript" src="путь"></script>
), не динамически. Просто js-файлов много, в ручную сложно объявить в нужном порядке и в полном объеме все эти js-файлы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто решить проблему очередности невозможно( в случае отсутствия декларирования зависимостей ), а сгенерить пути ко всем скриптам элементарно просто, наваять какой-то скрипт вида

```
 dir.getFiles().forEach(function( path ) {
    html += '<script src="/js/' + path">'+  +'\n'
 });
```

Можно легко реализовать на том-же JS'e средствами node.js или phantom.js, либо, даже, на том-же php, python.

Это немного облегчит процесс, а для "интеллектуальной" генерации нужна информация о зависимостях или искусственный интеллект. Вообще, о таких вопросах нужно думать до того, как писать так много кода.

На будущее, если кода действительно много, то, по хорошему, JS нужно подключать не script'ом, а через какую-то модульную систему ( можно реализовать, например, как в node.js, можно воспользоватся готовыми решениями, не суть ). Таким образом, каждый модуль, если ему необходим тот или иной функционал - сам-же его себе и подключает и проблем очередности и "недоподключения" не возникает.

Ну и, потом, конечно, можно без особых проблем написать парсер, который будет парсить все зависимости и, например, генерировать 1 единственный app.min.js, который потом, еще, можно чем-то поджать и смело в production.

---

простое доходчивое описание реализации [node.js модульной систему](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) AMD

Пара примеров готовых решений:

- http://requirejs.org/
- http://headjs.com/

Лично я предпочитая подход node.js, да, загрузка модулей синхронная, но, это только упрощает код, к тому-же, если написать парсер, о котором я писал выше - это вообще неважно. Ну и, в этом случае, иногда, можно вообще без модификаций использовать node.js модули на клиенте и наоборот. Хотя, решающим фактором является последнее, ну и однообразие клиентского и серверного кода.

В общем-то я написал очень простую [браузерную реализацию](http://require.alexwindhope.com/), работает идентично тому, как работает в node (за исключением кастомной логики на основе расширения файла, но это, как по мне, уже лишнее).
Еще раз повторюсь - в production с этим идти не стоит( в таком виде, в котором у вас будет приложение, по хорошему обязательно надо будет все собрать до кучи ), в прочем, как и с 100500 тегами скрипт в html'e, что, по сути, одно и тоже.

---

Ах да, еще 1 причина почему модули лучше сделать синхронными, например есть модуль, которому для своей коректной работы нужно подключить другой, это уже, волей не волей, становится проблемой т.к. больше буков либо, по сути, прямое указание зависимостей, что вообще ставит под сомнение целесообразность такого подхода. Ну и, для любого подключения любого модуля нам нужен будет callback, если модулей много, то это очень напрягает

Comment: Отличное решение проблемы. Спасибо!

Comment: @Антон Мухин - нет проблем, удачи

Answer (score 0):

Ну если я правильно понял, то суть задачи сводится к вставке большого обьема текста в большое количество файлов)))
Как вам вариант с обычной заменой в текстовом редакторе? :)

Берем любой продвинутый текстовый редактор (Notepad++, Sublime) и пишем, что заменить `<head></head>` на `<head>тут много подключенных скриптов</head>`. Выбираем поиск по директории и жмем Заменить все.

В том же notepad++ есть возможность замены по регулярке. Это на случай, если у вас в head'е сейчас что-то подключено.